# Comment Form Fields when user logged in

Tags: comments, cookies, comment-form

WordPress comments form automatically detects the name and email if you logged in. I want to disable this feature by adding a code snippet. The name and email fields should be filled by users and even admins also. Is this possible?

All visitors, admins, and users should see the same page every time.
I know you'll ask "why would you need them to fill in their information again?". Because I'm working on a cache solution which is strong and server-side.

[image: Ekran-Resmi-2019-09-05-14.28.04.png]

Thank you!
Best regards.

Comment: this sounds like a proposed solution to a problem, rather than asking about the original problem, even if you do this, it'll still take on the details of the logged in user, not the title and domain specified ( while annoying users who have to type it out then get different results anyway ). Have you considered just caching for users who are logged out instead? It's a much simpler and more effective way of doing it. Otherwise you also run the risk of caching other things such as cookies and nonces that could be used to exploit the site

Comment: As an aside, if you're trying to implement a static html based caching system, those already exist,like simple static https://www.simplystatic.co/, and you can use nginx/mod_rewrite rules to redirect logged in users to non-cached versions

Comment: @TomJNowell thank you for the response. Yes, I know the Nginx FastCGI cache and also LS Cache solutions. However, I'm trying to implement a different proxy cache for static content sites. (not for WooCommerce) This proxy cache excludes wp-admin page, post preview pages. And a plugin will help to purge the cache when you publish or edit a post. But It cannot exclude cookies. That's why I'm looking for a code snippet to disable admin&user comment cookies. Is that not possible? If I can do that thanks to you, I'll share a guide about implementation.

Comment: You can disable admin/user cookies but then there's no way to track logged in vs logged out on the frontend. If you can prevent cookies being set for the frontend and have only the admin cookie then you can probably get what you want without comment changes, but don't forget XMLRPC and the REST API are still a thing. You'll probably end up breaking parts of WP Admin if you don't figure out a bypass for the REST API

Comment: @TomJNowell Yes, I can bypass the REST API also. When a visitor submits a comment on my website, the page will redirect the visitor to "thank you, your comment is awaiting moderation" page. I created that "thank you" page and It is working well. Everything looks good. I can't fix the above comment issue only.

Comment: I don't want to change the WordPress core. Can I implement this via code snippet? Unfortunately, I'm not a PHP developer.